# High-speed signal across plane gap

Tags: pcb, signal, layout

I need to do a PCB layout where I have one digital signal that has relatively short rise/fall times crossing a slot in a GND plane. I know that this should not be done, because the signal return current should always flow directly under the PCB trace. But in this PCB desing, I have no other option.

So I thought it could be a good thing to place a capacitor (e.g. 1nF) across the GND plane slot. Then the signal return current can flow through that capacitor.

Does anyone have experience with such a kind of bridge capacitor across a GND slot? Is it possible to avoid radiation and/or reflection with this kind of setup? (I have to add that this PCB is extremely sensitive to EMI).

I know this is a very general question. I'm just seeking general advice from the cummunity.

Comment: You should do everything in your power to not have that gap there to begin with. Gaps are almost always not needed. Just separating parts on a single ground plane so noise currents from noisy parts don't flow under sensitive parts does the same thing but won't interfere with currents that actually do need to cross. A gap very easily introduces more EMI than it reduces. Why do you have no option?

Comment: You need to rethink why you've split the ground plane, what signals you're trying to avoid polluting what, and then have a signal going from one to the other. The two are not compatible.

Comment: Could be the slot in the ground plane is not to intentionally separate two grounds, but because of limited layer count and the need to use the ground plane layer for some routing. Not saying that's a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

That will provide a signal return path, but will also AC connect your two grounds.

Usually when I see split grounds, it's to prevent noise from one ground from affecting the other one.  You should take a look at what's near to the connection point and avoid having any noisy or sensitive circuits in the area.

Personally, I like to keep grounds together and try to route signals to localize noise--which also helps EMC--but every design is different, so you have to make your own call.

Comment: OK, the AC connection might be a problem. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

I find the "return current" argument to be a bit short-sighted, usually: Your high-speed line, **together** with the ground plane, forms a transmission line, in which the signal travels, in the space between these two. Slot one, and you've not built a worse signal line, you've built a slot antenna, a capacitive shunt, whatever.

So, don't do that, full stop. A coplanar wave guide might be what you're looking for if you can't have a proper microstrip line.

Comment: Thanks. It is actually a design of a team mate of mine and I already told him multiple times not to do it. But the alternative is going to hell and back again...

Answer (score 2):

If you couple noisy ground to signal ground, you are adding a CM noise signal. maybe good for earth to floating grounds but not on board.

Always isolate your high speed signal with stripline or microstrip, otherwise the impedance mismatch and added CM noise will add ringing and noise during some edges.

You have not define your EMI spectrum or rise time or PF of crosstalk , so we cannot say . But if you have a time limit and like to gamble without making proper design specs, put signal ground strips on both sides as close possible!!

Comment: The signal ground strips on both sides are a good idea. It is a prototype design so we can afford some playing around with different options.